# Unity ResolveAll<>() issue 3.5

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am having an issue with resolve all with Unity 3.5

I have multiple types registered in my container for the the same interface all registrations are named and can be resolved individually using their name

// This does not work , resolve all returns 0 items

```
moduleCompositions.AddRange(container.ResolveAll<IVpModuleComposition>());
```

// This does!!!! ????

```
var registrations = container.Registrations.Where(reg => reg.RegisteredType == typeof(IVpModuleComposition));

        registrations.ForEach(reg => 
            moduleCompositions.Add(container.Resolve<IVpModuleComposition>(reg.Name)));
```

If someone has any ideas it would be very much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please look at the question again I have said they are named and my temporary fix is resolving all of them using their names! So I don't get it.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue.  Could you show your code that does the registration?

Comment: Ok sorted,

I think this may be a unity bug , but it could also be by design. The issue with this was that another registered instance class that required the IEnumerable<IVpModuleComposition> was getting instantiated / resolved before the IVpModuleComposition's were registered. 

Seems that unity was caching this result and any further attempts to resolve all after they were registered failed. Yet the manual resolving still worked? 

Odd , but useful if anyone else have the same problem

Comment: If you could post some code to reproduce the issue, I could make sure it gets filed as a bug.  This one sounds fun too :)